# How to call an API while app is in background when app timeout period is exceeded?

Tags: ios, swift, background-process

In my app timeout time on no user activity is set to 10 minutes.. after 10 minutes of idle time is over , user is logged out of app ... We have recently added a chat page in our app.. Now when app goes into background & app timeout period has exceeded, we need to call an API to server to end active chat session from server end because user may open app from background any time in future, we don't want session to keep persists as session termination api is only called when app is in foreground now.

So requirements in short are :

1)Keep track of idle app time in foreground & even app moves into background.(should we use background processing modes to keep track of time in background mode as well?).

2)Whenever idle app timeout period is exceed(10 minutes) while app is in background hit an api call to end active chat session.(Its working fine in foreground)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Websocket, there's ping / pong technique to know device is disconnected.

Server should ping client every interval time to know it's still alive or offline because of any reasons, like network changes, not only by app moving to background.

When connection is established, server is holding client information it will know which client to ping, and wait for client to pong.

To control user's sessions, people usually use access-token. For your case, access token is valid in 10 mins. When client send a request to server, if token expired we use refresh token to ask new access token and retry the previous request with new valid token.

Refresh token has longer expiration. Like 30 days or 90 days or even never expired.

Comment: actually chat is just a web page with which we are interacting to detect links etc...when app timeout period is exceeded we are also calling an api to end chat session from server. So in foreground its fine.. I just need to keep track of app timeout interval in background as well & when timeout time is exceeded hit an api from background...So there is no such roles of refresh tokens etc here..

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks you can start a scheduled background task when user move app to background, on the page above, there's sample code https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/refreshing_and_maintaining_your_app_using_background_tasks

Comment: Have you managed to solve this? I also need to keep the web socket connection alive while in the background, but I am reading the documentation and idk if it is possible to keep the socket sonnection

Comment: @Igniti0n I think no need to do that because Apple prevent background use for long time. We can establish new socket session when application back to foreground.

Comment: @QuangHà This seems to be a slight problem for me, I am building a watchOS app, and it's annoying for users when the watch closes, to have to wait a sec for the socket connection to be re-established :/. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: How about applying some techniques that are mention in this WWDC video? I think can help to reduce connection latency for speeding up your watch app. https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/10078/